# Dynamic page routing in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hello I am trying to learn React with e-shop use case. I have 200 000 items in database which are grouped into categories. Each product or each product categories should be accessible directly via the following form of url:

for products:

http://domain/product_name 

http://domain/product_name2

etc..

for categories (representing menu) 
http://domain/laptops/gaming 
will display
product_name and product_name2 
etc..

Since categories and products will add/modify each night, Router component would have to be "re-created" in order to correctly handle routes for new products and categories, since i am not using paths like
http://domain/product/product_name... I can't use static route like

path=/product/:id 
...

I have a simple PHP rest api, which returns what's the type of path 
http://domain/product_name   ->type product
http://domain/laptops/gaming ->type section

based on such an `api` i can correctly determine component to use to render the object via following code (rest api call removed to keep the code as simple as possible)

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import ShowProduct from './components/showProduct.js'
import ShowSection from './components/showSection.js'

const PageLocator=({var1})=>{
        {/* determine from rest API if requested path is type of product or section

        if product */}
        return <div><ShowProduct product={var1.path} /></div>


        {/* if section */}
        return <div><ShowSection section={var1.path}

        {/* if etc...  */}
}

class App extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return(
                  <Router>
                    <div>
                        <PageLocator path="/" var1={{path:window.location.pathname}} />
                    </div>
                </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

The code above actually does what I expect. Problem I am facing is that I can't validate the solution as the right way due to my zero experience with React so I would like to ask someone to validate and eventually advise how can I handle such a requirement with React.

Comment: You say that it works right? That's validation. Most good programmers can help you fix things that don't work, and great programmers will commend you for coming here to ask a question -- but your questions have to be specific. There are many ways to solve the same problem.

Comment: Yes, it's working, but i am "Padawan" and maybe it has some impact i can't assess at this moment or it's total step out. For the reason I asked here

Comment: Because there are many ways to tackle a problem, "doing it the right way" is almost always based on someone's opinion -- something stackoverflow aims to stay away from. Come back here anytime with specific questions, in the meantime there are places like reddit and discord where you can get general feedback. Happy coding!